# React Native: No propType for native prop RCTView.maxHeight

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, npm, react-native

After upgrading to RN **0.30** I started seeing the error shown below even when building the simplest possible [app](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html):

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

- The strangest is that components `BlurView`, `VibrancyView` and `RNSearchBar` are included in the warning messages despite the project not using them.
- Recompiling/cleaning the project doesn't fix the problem.

Console & error:

```
2016-07-22 08:48:02.985 [warn][tid:main][RCTEventEmitter.m:52] Sending `websocketFailed` with no listeners registered.
2016-07-22 08:48:03.031 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "BlurView" does not exist
2016-07-22 08:48:03.032 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "VibrancyView" does not exist
2016-07-22 08:48:03.033 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "RNSearchBar" does not exist
2016-07-22 08:48:03.040 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] `Constructor` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.maxHeight` of native type `CGFloat`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.
2016-07-22 08:48:03.043 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: `Constructor` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.maxHeight` of native type `CGFloat`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.
2016-07-22 08:48:03.102 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
2016-07-22 08:48:03.104 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It suggests that your js and native code are out of sync. Have you tried "react-native upgrade" ?

Comment: Trying this didn't help, all my packages are up to date, I'm using React Native v. `0.30`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The reason for this error was that another instance of React packager (still on `0.28`) was running in the background at the time after I updated to `0.30`.

Restarting React packager solved the problem.

Comment: Because the packager can be running in a background process don't forget to check with `lsof -n -i4TCP:8081`.

Comment: How to 'Restart React packager'?

Comment: @Negin Basiri on OSX it usually opens up a separate terminal window just close that and run your xcode project again.

Comment: In my case, it was the packager running into a different project. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 8):

I restarted the react native by *react-native start* and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this same error message, although in my case it was caused by incompatibilities between dependencies.

What I did to solve it was:

1. Create a new project using `create-react-native-app foo`. This should install compatible dependencies.
2. Open your project's `package.json` and update the versions of the dependencies to match those in foo's `package.json`.
3. Check that *expo* version match the `sdkVersion` in the file `app.json` and update if necessary.
4. Delete `node_modules` and reinstall all the packages.

I hope it helps!

Comment: waow this was a doozy. This was the only solution that worked me... don't know how I would have tracked this down otherwise. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case react-server and react-project were mismatched. I was running the wrong project with the wrong Node server.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing of the above worked for me, but `yarn cache clean` did the trick.

Comment: or, `react-native start --reset-cache` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`